# Timescaledb refresh_lag - how to make it to ignore certain rows

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have no results in `my_table` and `my_table_hourly` table. I executed this:

```
ALTER VIEW my_table SET (
  timescaledb.refresh_lag = '30 days',
  timescaledb.refresh_interval = '15 minutes',
  timescaledb.max_interval_per_job = '1 week'
);
```

Then, I inserted a new row:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
(schedule_time, id)
VALUES('2023-12-12 17:00:00.000 +0100', 1);
```

And after that I refreshed a view:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED view my_table_hourly
```

Because of `refresh_lag` I expect that rows newer than 30 days wouldn't be take into account, but it was actually inserted into aggregated table:

```
select * from my_table_hourly
-- found 1 result
```

Why does that happen? Do I understand `refresh_lag` wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old version (1.7?)

I would encourage you to move to 2.13, there have been many changes in the CAGG space since then.